# Three equal sized buttons in Bootstraper

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've started to use bootstraper. And I want a row with three buttons. The buttons should have the same height and width. How can I achieve this?

I have come up with the following, but this gives me different heights of the buttons.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 offset1">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
            <div class="buttonbody">
                <img src=".." />
                <p>Button1<br />Second row<p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="span2 offset1">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
            <div class="buttonbody">
                <img src=".." />
                <p>Button2<p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="span2 offset1">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
            <div class="buttonbody">
                <img src=".." />
                <p>Button3<p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same height, you'll have to use jQuery to calculate the max then apply it to all the elements that should have the same height:

```
var selector = ".row-fluid .buttonbody";
var maxHeight = 0;
$(selector).each(function() {
    var selfHeight = $(this).height();
    if (selfHeight > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = selfHeight;
    }
});
// set the same height on all elements
$(selector).height(maxHeight);
```

**UPDATE:** To resize buttons each time the window is resized, you can do the following:

```
// declare a function to be called
// each time buttons need to be resized
var resizeButtons = function() {
    var selector = ".row-fluid .buttonbody";
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        var selfHeight = $(this).height();
        if (selfHeight > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = selfHeight;
        }
    });
    // set the same height on all elements
    $(selector).height(maxHeight);
}

$(function() {
    // attach function to the resize event
    $(window).resize(resizeButtons);

    // call function the first time window is loaded;
    resizeButtons();
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! This works as expected. Can I get an event when the page is resized so I can run this code again?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer : http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2942/

Long Answer:

The following code does what you want.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="btn"><strong>Button 1</strong></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn"><strong>Button 2</strong></a>
    <a href="#" class="btn"><strong>Button 3</strong></a>
</div>​
```

Here is [tutorial](http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/row-of-buttons) for the same.

I recommend you go through twitter bootstrap documenation and [bootsnipp.com](http://bootsnipp.com) for more information.

From your comments, as you say you are using `<br/>` you can use the following : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2943/),

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="btn"><strong>Button 1<br/>Second row</strong></a>
<a href="#" class="btn"><strong>Button 2<br/>&nbsp;</strong></a>
<a href="#" class="btn"><strong>Button 3<br/>&nbsp;</strong></a>
</diV>​
```

Comment: Thank you! But I doesnt seem to work. Notice in the first button that I have a <br/> and a second row. This gives me a higher button than the others. I want all button to have the same height!

Comment: @ErikZ have update my answer, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2943/)

Comment: You're smart. :) But what if the images have different height? My goal is to populate these buttons from code and regardeless of what they contain should the all have the same height. Is it possible at all?